# Change datetimepicker displayed date

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I am using Visual Studio 2010 C# and I would like to change how datetimepicker's textbox displays the date I pick.

By default, it is for example 13-Jul-2013. I want to change it in `yyyy-mm-dd` format because i want to store this in database column with date values.

I tried the following code but I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

```
  datetimepicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
  datetimepicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd";
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Your code worked for me

Comment: Won't `mm` be ***minutes*** instead of months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is how your datetimepicker is created. Just Create Your Own at runtime using

```
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd";
    //You can play with this to change location
    dateTimePicker1.Location = new Point(20, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(dateTimePicker1);
}
```

Comment: You were absolutely right, I tried your code and it worked out just as I wanted ! Thank you so much for your time !